# How to change display name of Excel VSTO add-in?

Tags: excel, vsto, ms-office, add-in

How to change display name (shown in the Excel's list of installed add-ins) of an Excel VSTO add-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This name can be specified in the ClickOnce installer settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that's the name of your actual VSTO project, echoed through to the .manifest file for the addin that is generated during the compile process...

Look at the end of the Manifest for the vsto3FriendlyName element.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the GA_Ribbon class,

Please change the tab name and display name so that the addin tab will be displayed as it needs to be

```
 this.tab1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
 this.tab1.Label = "newlabel";
 this.tab1.Name = "newname";
```